# TypedArray displays its values as NaN when rendering in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I recently needed to use the `Float32Array` typed-array, which will be used to render a list of elements (regardless in what type of format - e.g. an `<ul>` with `<li>` as each element of my array). For some reason, when I try to render the values, I get `NaN` even though the `isNaN()` call returns `false` moreover the `typeof` of each element is `number` **and** the console prints just fine the values. For example:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { channels: new Float32Array([1, 2, 3, 4]) };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.channels.map((val, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{val}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This one prints a series of `NaNNaNNaNNaN` (not even distributing them in proper `<li>` elements. I expect to have the values printed as they are already stored in the array.

Is there any reason for which the rendering doesn't work for types arrays (as expected) but works just fine in console logging? (or am I doing actually something wrong?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason it's doing that is because Float32Array#map() expects the callback to return a number, and the method itself returns a Float32Array. What you'd want to do is convert it to an Array first and then map it:

```
Array.from(this.state.channels).map((val, i) => ...)
```

Comment: Kinda makes sense. But now, the `val` will contain the entire array (not really considering each individual value) and this will result into a single `<li>`.

Comment: Oh, woops, I guess you have to call .values() on channels before passing it to Array(). I've updated my post.

Comment: Wait, no, nevermind, it was supposed to be Array.from(), not Array()

Comment: That's right :) Having the iterator from `values()` doesn't help to perform the mapping. Thanks!